# Filter max 20 values from a list of integers

Tags: python, list, max

I'd like to create a list *maxValues* containing top 20 values from a list of integers *lst*.

```
maxValues = []
for i in range(20):
  maxValues.append(max(lst))
  lst.remove(max(lst))
```

Is there a more compact code for achieving this task or even built-in function?

Comment: It's not just compactness. Your code (if corrected, the `del` statement is wrong) is O(n*k), while the other methods are O(nlogn).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's [`heapq.nlargest()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
maxvalues = heapq.nlargest(20, lst)
```

From the doc:

> `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)`
>
> Return a list with the *n* largest elements from the dataset defined by *iterable*. *key*, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in *iterable* (for example, `key=str.lower`). Equivalent to: `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`.

Or at the same way use [`heapq.nsmallest()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) if you want the smallest.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** [from the doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html#module-heapq):

> The latter two functions [`nlargest()` and `nsmallest()`] perform best for smaller values of *n*. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#sorted) function. Also, when `n==1`, it is more efficient to use the built-in [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#max) functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required, consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

Comment: Thanks. That is better than my answer. Likely to be faster when the list is very long because there is no need to sort the whole list.

Comment: @Rémi: I added a note from the doc that compares when the two solutions.

Answer (score 8):

```
sorted(lst)[-20:]
```

is the shortest I can think of. Likely to be faster, too.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it's more complete but I used your simple fast solution.