# More pythonic way to find first two greatest value in a list in python

Tags: python

These days I design some algorithms in python, but find first two greatest value in python is too ugly and inefficient.

How to implement it in a efficient or a pythonic way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter max 20 values from a list of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757289/filter-max-20-values-from-a-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found this to be consistently faster (about 2x for a list of 1,000,000 items) than `heapq.nlargest`:

```
def two_largest(sequence):
    first = second = 0
    for item in sequence:
        if item > second:
            if item > first:
                first, second = item, first
            else:
                second = item
    return first, second
```

(function modified at the suggestion of MatthieuW)

Here are the results of my testing (`timeit` was taking forever, so I used `time.time()`):

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> from time import time
>>> seq = range(1000000)
>>> shuffle(seq)
>>> def time_it(func, *args, **kwargs):
...     t0 = time()
...     func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return time() - t0
...

>>> #here I define the above function, two_largest().
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> time_it(nlargest, 2, seq)
0.258958101273
>>> time_it(two_largest, seq)
0.145977973938
```

Comment: You should compare with second, then first. In a 1000000 items list (unless it is sorted), most will be less than current "second", so you can avoid one comparison per item.

Comment: @MatthieuW: Good point! I was actually surprised that an interpreted script worked faster than any of the builtins.

Comment: At least on Python 2.7, the `heapq` module is also implemented as an interpreted Python script, not as C code. So your result isn't that surprising.

Comment: one can use `first = second = None` to include negative numbers in a clean way, doesn't work for python3 though..

Answer (score 16):

Most Pythonic way is to use [`nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq
values = heapq.nlargest(2, my_list)
```

Comment: Or just use the builtin sorted. `values = sorted(my_list, reverse=True)[:2]`

Comment: @Christian: That would be both slower and (in my opinion) less Pythonic.

Comment: @interjay: for small lists `sort()` might be faster.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian How small means small? any concrete number suggestions? What if list has 20-100 elements.

Comment: @RichardWong: On my computer I get similar speeds for 100 elements.

Comment: @richardWong: use nlargest() both for readability and a better asymptotic complexity. if profiler says that for your data `nlargest` is a bottleneck then you could try sort() to see how it compares.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [100 , 2000 , 1 , 5]
mylist.sort()
biggest = mylist[-2:]
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting sorting. This is just plain horrible. No need to sort in order to find the largest two elements.

Comment: @MichaelWild, its true that sorting ain't needed for **n** largest nos. But even [nlargest](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) says **Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]**

Comment: @tuxuday - it is equivalent in the result, not in the performance. It uses `sorted` only when `n>size`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
a=int(input('Enter the first number:'))
b=int(input('Enter the second Number:'))
c=int(input('Ente the Third Number:'))
if a>b and a>c:
    print('the value of A is',a,'highest velue')
elif b>a and b>c:
    print('the value of B is',b,'highest velue')
elif c>a and c>b:
    print('the value of C is',c,'highest velue')
else:
   print('the value is equls')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.